Azure DevOps Next.js Azure App Service deploy success but not working
I have a simple Next app that I'm trying to deploy to Azure App Service. When I run the buiild pipeline in ADO it succeeds but the website isn't showing up. This is my pipeline:
trigger: none

variables:
  # replace with your Azure service connection name
  azureSubscription: 'My Service Connection'
  # replace with your web app name
  webAppName: 'my-web-app'
  # replace with your working directory name if not the root directory
  workingDirectory: '.'
  # replace with your Node.js version
  nodeVersion: '20.x'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: $(nodeVersion)
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install and build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
      
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon'

And in the package.json I have updated my start scrip to be "start": "next start -p $PORT"
Despite this running 'successfully' in ADO it is showing a hosted 404 Screen and I'm not sure why.


You can open the Log stream page as mentioned here, then deploy the WebApp again. This way you can see the detailed log during the deployment or the error message when you access the site. If there are any error message, please share the log here. You can also download the published pipeline artifact and check if the files are correct to deploy.

Hi @keybored, since the deployment job in azure devops is successful, you can check your code and App Service configurations to find out if there are something wrong.

In order to deploy your Next.js Web app successfully via azure devops pipeline refer the steps below:-
Make sure to use the startup command below for the Web app to work:-
 - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: siliconwebapp655'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxxxxxxxxxcb2a7)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: 'siliconwebapp'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
              startUpCommand: 'next start'

My Azure Devops yaml pipeline:-
trigger:
- main

variables:

  azureSubscription: '5b7e6xxxxxxxx94d93'

  webAppName: 'silicxxxx'

  environmentName: 'silicxxxx'

  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: siliconwebapp655'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (01xxxxxxxxxxa7)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: 'silicoxxxx'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
              startUpCommand: 'next start'

This is my package.json:-
{
  "name": "next-sid",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.3.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.6",
    "next": "13.4.6",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  }
}

Output:-

